# Parametrization of Volume of intersection of two balls

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I am trying to find a parametrization of the volume of intersection of two balls $(x-\alpha)^2+y^2+z^2 \leq R^2$ and $(x+\alpha)^2+y^2+z^2 \leq R^2$ , where $R \geq \alpha$, Also , How to find volume in terms of $R$ and $\alpha$?

The intersection looks something like a solid rugby ball or solid ellipsoid, and when $R \to \alpha$, intersection is just a point. Also, $\alpha =0$ corresponds to the whole ball.

The volume can be calculated using volume of revolution, I don't get the parametrization part.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to think of it like this we have two spheres which intersect only difference is in x-position of centers, something like this:

[image]

[image]

so if you look at this like an intersection in x-direction, your volume formula should express the space from Sphere 1 to Sphere 2. As seen from picture (sorry for ugly picture) the intersection in yz is located on the x=0. If $x=0$ your yz orthogonal projection gives you a circle:

$$z^2+y^2=R^2-a^2$$

so projection is easily obtained with:

$y=r cos(\phi), z=r sin(\phi)$

and in x direction you go from Sphere 1 to Sphere 2, so the volume integral should look something like this:

$$ \int^{2\pi}_0 d\phi \int^{\sqrt{R^2-a^2}}_0 r dr \int^{a+\sqrt{R^2-r^2}}_{a-\sqrt{R^2-r^2}} dx $$

$$ =\int^{2\pi}_0 d\phi \int^{\sqrt{R^2-a^2}}_0 r\left[a+\sqrt{R^2-r^2}-a+\sqrt{R^2-r^2}\right] dr=$$

$$ =2\int^{2\pi}_0 d\phi \int^{\sqrt{R^2-a^2}}_0 r\left[\sqrt{R^2-r^2}\right] dr $$

$$ =-2\int^{2\pi}_0 d\phi \int^{\sqrt{R^2-a^2}}_0 \left[\sqrt{R^2-r^2}\right] d(R^2-r^2) $$

$$ =-2\int^{2\pi}_0 d\phi \frac{2}{3}\sqrt{(R^2-r^2)^3}|^{\sqrt{R^2-a^2}}_0  $$

$$ =-\frac{4}{3}\int^{2\pi}_0  \sqrt{(a^2)^3} - \sqrt{(R^2)^3} d\phi $$

$$ =\frac{4}{3}\int^{2\pi}_0  R^3 - a^3 d\phi $$

$$ =\frac{8\pi}{3}(R^3 - a^3) $$

Hope this helps...